# CiviCRM Contact,get with group - change in result format

Tags: api, documentation

*Where (which JIRA issue, if any) did this change in API behaviour come from, and was it documented/expected?*

The same `Contact,get` API call returns different results between 4.6 and 4.7.

IMO the new style is better, but I'm not sure the change was intended/documented. (I want clarification so I can expect the new behaviour to stick!)

I've confirmed this behaviour today by testing on the [4.6 (Joomla)](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/) and [4.7 (Drupal)](http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/) demo sites.

API call for `Contact,get` with `return=group` shows groups in the results.

```
civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => "group",
  'id' => 3,
));
```

In 4.6 the result has groups shown by their group "title" (not name). Since group titles may contain a comma, there is some lack of certainty in the results (leading to [workarounds like this](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/blob/37267ab82260caed96078ead60c4e71c18b5cc2d/CRM/Mailchimp/Utils.php#L27)).

```
[
  'is_error' => 0,
  'version' => 3,
  'count' => 1,
  'id' => 3,
  'values' => [
    [
      'contact_id' => '3',
      'groups' => 'Example group,Example smart group',
      'id' => '3',
    ]
  ]
]
```

In 4.7 the result has groups shown by their group ID, which is a bit more predictable to work with.

```
[
  'is_error' => 0,
  'version' => 3,
  'count' => 1,
  'id' => 3,
  'values' => [
    [
      'contact_id' => '3',
      'groups' => '4,7',
      'id' => '3',
    ]
  ]
]
```

I've checked the [CiviCRM API Changelog](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/API+changes) and enquired on chat.civicrm.org without any luck so far. Help me, SE!

Comment: Monish points to [civicrm/civicrm-core @ 3875e6b6](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/3875e6b655e6ee13b11ccee31cd3a3c0421a0724#diff-e54381bfdf51e31cab376c71ca0d66ffR5694) as origin of the change; if true, this means the API change appears with 4.7.11 via [CRM-17123: Include Transaction ID in membership bulk entry profile](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17123). Not sure that relates to `Contact,get`, perhaps the JIRA issue referenced in the commit is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but were I to post it as a comment the whole thing would be on one line/unreadable. It seems to me that the most desirable format is:

```
[
  'is_error' => 0,
  'version' => 3,
  'count' => 1,
  'id' => 3,
  'values' => [
    [
      'contact_id' => '3',
      'groups' => array(4, 7),
      'id' => '3',
    ]
  ]
]
```

... or even:

```
[
  'is_error' => 0,
  'version' => 3,
  'count' => 1,
  'id' => 3,
  'values' => [
    [
      'contact_id' => '3',
      'groups' => array('Example group', 'Example smart group'),
      'group_ids' => array(4, 7),
      'id' => '3',
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: I do like that idea. Structure is good.